# filter_url_params in magento 2 Ui component is not working properly anybody have solution

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, filter, parameter

I want to show data according to the id that is shown in my URL.....
my URL is

> http://dev.magento.com/admin/customer/index/edit/id/1/key/06ae49324c0bb7e328bc5bd4bb75954fcc787d538a59cb97ce4e1809a1a17ff3/#

my code is

```
<item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="customer_id" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
```

When I call this it treats "id" as a string and matches "id" as a string in my table column "customer_id" rather than its value.

- when I call "*" instead of "id" it gives me a full database record
- when I call a specific value like "2" it returns me records of customer_id "2"
- when I call "id" it returns me values of customer_id "0"

kindly someone please help!!!

Comment: hey how are you! I'm actually looking for something like this, were you able to solve this? thanks in advance

Comment: hi, i am fine . no i can't solve it in this way i solved it by another way

Comment: Can you please help me? which method did you use? is there any link you can give me so I can guide? Thanks!

Comment: i don't remember the link and also i checked my extension i that problem is still pending for me sorry can't help in this

Answer (score 1):

You need add parameter name "customer_id" to your url.
And change `<item name="customer_id" xsi:type="string">id</item>` to `<item name="customer_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>`

Answer (score 1):

change di.xml and add replace `<virtualType>` of datasource with `<type>`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="blackout_data_source" xsi:type="string">
                vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\BlackoutLimit\Grid\Collection
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Add `<Type>` of grid/collection in same di.xml as below add variables name "maintable" "eventPrefix" "eventObject"

```
<type name="vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\BlackoutLimit\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">tm_blackout_days_limit</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">tm_blackoutlimit_blackout_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">blackout_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\BlackoutLimit</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Create Grid collection file as below

```
vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\BlackoutLimit\Grid\Collection.php


<?php
```

namespace vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\BlackoutLimit\Grid;

class Collection extends \vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\BlackoutLimit\Collection implements
\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface
{

```
protected $_idFieldName = 'day_limit_id';
protected $_eventPrefix = 'tm_blackoutlimit_blackout_collection';
protected $_eventObject = 'blackout_collection';

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory            
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger            
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy            
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager            
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager            
 * @param mixed|null $mainTable            
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $eventPrefix            
 * @param mixed $eventObject            
 * @param mixed $resourceModel            
 * @param string $model            
 * @param null $connection            
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
 *            @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 *            
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory, 
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger, \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy, 
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager, 
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, $mainTable, $eventPrefix, $eventObject, $resourceModel, 
    $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document', $connection = null, \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null)
{ 
    parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
    $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
    $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
    $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

/**
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface
 */
public function getAggregations()
{
    return $this->aggregations;
}

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface $aggregations            
 * @return void
 */
public function setAggregations($aggregations)
{
    $this->aggregations = $aggregations;
}

/**
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaInterface|null
 */
public function getSearchCriteria()
{
    return $this->searchCriteria;
}

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria            
 * @return $this @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setSearchCriteria(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
{
    $this->searchCriteria = $searchCriteria;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get total count.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getTotalCount()
{
    return $this->getSize();
}

/**
 * Set total count.
 *
 * @param int $totalCount            
 * @return $this @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
{
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set items list.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface[] $items            
 * @return $this @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function setItems(array $items = null)
{
    return $this;
}

/**
 * This is the function that will add the filter
 */
    protected function _beforeLoad()
    {   
parent::_beforeLoad();
        $mydate=getdate(date("U"));
        $this->addFieldTOFilter( 'day_code',array( 'like' => '%'."$mydate[year]".'%' ) );            
        return $this;
    }    
}
```